# [Talos] I am trying to launch talos in simulation but gazebo Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic, rosparam, robot-description

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was trying to play with talos robot in simulation. I have installed the simulation using [this](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TALOS/Tutorials/Installation/Simulation) tutorial in ros-melodic ubuntu 18.04. got some errors but I was able to solve it. I have error free build and all the files have solved missing arguments errors (That I was facing).

when I launch the robot in rviz, it works like a charm. so I thought launching in gazebo to test physics. There were many errors which I was able to solve but one error still remains at the end.

```
[ INFO] [1648586058.460195637, 30.401000000]: gazebo_ros_control plugin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [robot_description] on the ROS param server.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
================================================================================REQUIRED process [gazebo-2] has died!
process has died [pid 16089, exit code 139, cmd /home/aarsh/henrique_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/scripts/gzserver -e ode worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/aarsh/.ros/log/83708ae4-af9f-11ec-87e7-ac2b6e45babe/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/aarsh/.ros/log/83708ae4-af9f-11ec-87e7-ac2b6e45babe/gazebo-2*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[rgbd/rgb/image_proc-5] killing on exit
[rgbd/rgb/high_res/image_proc_high_res-4] killing on exit
[gazebo-2] killing on exit
[gazebo_gui-3] killing on exit
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

NOTE : There is the `/robot_description` parameter present in the param list.

So I removed the `libgazebo_ros_control.so` from [this](https://github.com/pal-robotics/talos_robot/blob/kinetic-devel/talos_description/gazebo/gazebo.urdf.xacro) file and tried to launch it again and it works without the `libgazebo_ros_control.so`.  It is not at all the issue of the tags inside the plugin `<ns></ns>`  `<robotSimType>pal_hardware_gazebo/PalHardwareGazebo</robotSimType>`
 `<robotNamespace></robotNamespace>`
 `<controlPeriod>0.001</controlPeriod>` I have tried removing all of them and still I get the same error.

When I remove the whole plugin, it works perfectly. Just robot falls down due to gravity.

Let me know if you need any further info.

Thank you for helping.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398192/%5Btalos%5D-i-am-trying-to-launch-talos-in-simulation-but-gazebo-segmentation-fault-(core-dumped)./) by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2022-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2022-03-29**:
Hello, This could be the gazebo_ros_control plugin provided by PAL Robotics, is not properly compiled in your workspace. I recommend you to clean your workspace and build again and also check for any running gazebo servers in the background and kill them before launching the simulation. You can also open an issue in the GitHub repository : https://github.com/pal-robotics/talos_tutorials with the issues you faced and resolved on your own, so we can take a look.

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-03-30**:
Hello sir, Thank you for your inputs, I will try to do the suggested and will report the updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out the issue, Pal is using modified `ros_controller` and the `transmission_interface` package. hence they are using the boost shared pointer and not the std shared pointer (which is used in the ros kinetic and above). I thought the `ros_controller` comes with talos simulation is the same that comes in melodic so I did not built it, but its not the same. it is modified one.

Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) with karma: 328 on 2022-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2022-04-01**:
@aarsh_t at PAL Robotics we use the ROS Control with some custom fixes and features on our end. Unless you compile the the ros_control packages as per the . rosinstall, you might have troubles testing some controllers. If not change the gazebo plugin and things might work.

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-04-01**:
Aha I see! I tried to fixed the shared pointer things for one of the package and it built successfully but I didn't knew you have also modifications from your side. Well, nice to learn something new! now I might dig the modifications from the original package as well haha. Thanks for the info ;)